# Sample from the posterior of normal model using rstan?

Tags: r, bayesian, sampling, stan, rstan

I have a very simple Bayesian model $y_j \mid \mu ,\sigma^2 \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, $\mu \sim N(0,100)$, $\sigma \sim InvGamma(0.01,0.01)$. I am try to sample from the posterior using `rstan`. However, I get the following error

**RStan code (normal.stan)**

```
data {
  int n;
  vector[n] y;
}

parameters{
  real mu;
  real<lower = 0> sigma;
}
model{
  target += normal_lpdf(y | mu, sigma);
  target += normal_lpdf(mu | 0, 100)
  target += inv_gamma_lpdf(sigma | 0.01, 0.01);
}
```

**R Code**

```
require(rstanarm)
require(rstan)
# Simulation
n <- 500; 
set.seed(111)
y <- rnorm(n,0,1)

posterior <- stan(file   = "normal.stan", 
             data   = list(y, n),          
             warmup = 1000,                 
             iter   = 11000,                
             chains = 1)
```

However, when I run the R code, the `posterior` object is empty.

I would appreciate any hints.

Comment: You'll probably get more help if you post in the stan forums: https://discourse.mc-stan.org/latest.

Answer (score 1):

The list of data that you pass to the `stan` function must be a named list, like

```
data = list(y = y, n = n),
```